# How can I create a NEW column in a dataframe based on values of another column in a DIFFERENT dataframe that have common information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment, multi-index

I have a dataframe:

This is for work so I am just going to make it simple and put a minimal amount of data in it, I call this one data:

```
| induction date |    shop        |
| -------------- | -------------- |
|2021-07-18      | AD9            |
| 2021-07-26     | DL9            |
```

I want to add a third column called WIP that grabs the WIP from another dataframe (multi-index) of this format based on the matching of the induction date and the SHOP, I call this one WIP:

```
                                  |  WIP  |
                                  |-------|
| date           |    shop        |       |
| -------------- | -------------- |       |
| 2021-07-18     | AD9            |   7   |
| 2021-07-26     | DL9            |   3   |
```

I haven't had any luck though, I've tried converting the WIP dataframe to a dictionary and using map but it's not working, I get a key error. I don't know if it's because of the multi-level index or what, but I'm stuck.

I also tried just assigning it by referencing the WIP dataframe and the original columns like so:

```
data['WIP']=WIPbyShop.loc[data['DATE_INDUCTED', 'SHOP']].WIP
```

but this gives me a key error. Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I feel like there should be a pretty simple way to do this and like I'm over complicating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) specifying the `on` keyword argument to tell it to align the MultiIndex to columns in `data`:

```
data = data.join(WIPbyShop['WIP'], on=['induction date', 'shop'])
```

`data`:

```
  induction date shop  WIP
0     2021-07-18  AD9    7
1     2021-07-26  DL9    3
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'induction date': ['2021-07-18', '2021-07-26'], 
    'shop': ['AD9', 'DL9']
})

# Reversed DataFrame rows to show alignment
WIPbyShop = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021-07-26', '2021-07-18'], 
    'shop': ['DL9', 'AD9'],
    'WIP': [3, 7]
}).set_index(['date', 'shop'])
```

```
# data
  induction date shop
0     2021-07-18  AD9
1     2021-07-26  DL9

# WIPbyShop
                 WIP
date       shop     
2021-07-26 DL9     3
2021-07-18 AD9     7
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but this gave: ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: One of your date columns is a datetime and one is string. You should make them either both string or both datetimes.

Comment: No they are both datetime I just double checked.

Comment: That cannot be the case if you're getting an error saying that one is object and one is datetime64[ns]

Comment: Okay you're right I added in an additional line using pd.to_datetime for the WIP date column and it fixed the issue, and that now works. Thank you for the quick response!